# GetSiteAndWeb access denied after Office365 service update - why?

Tags: rest, authentication, claims-based-auth, access-denied

Typically this call GetSiteAndWeb, using Office365 authentication, does not require extra authentication to succeed. This call starts failing recently at subsite level (but still ok on site collection level).   Although uncertain, timing points to an Office365 service update.  And I have no visibility to whether there is additional admin change.

- What are the possible reason(s) for access denied for this call to start failing?
- Any suggested action to troubleshoot this?

Request:

```
POST https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/projects/myProject/_layouts/15/start.aspx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: myApp/7.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetSiteAndWeb"
Host: mysite.sharepoint.com
Content-Length: 439
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetSiteAndWeb xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><strUrl>https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/projects/myproject/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/de</strUrl></GetSiteAndWeb></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required: https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/15/error.aspx&Source=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fstart.aspx
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Return_Url: https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/error.aspx
X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: ec72f19c-20dd-1000-b497-23bac5a0fc1a
request-id: ec72f19c-20dd-1000-b497-23bac5a0fc1a
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 35
SPIisLatency: 1
X-IDCRL_AUTH_PARAMS_V1: IDCRL Type="BPOSIDCRL", EndPoint="/sites/projects/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/", RootDomain="sharepoint.com", Policy="MBI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.3722
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2015 18:45:56 GMT
Content-Length: 13

403 FORBIDDEN
```

Answer (score 1):

Using fiddler and my own test tenant I reproduced your issue.  After adding the FedAuth and rtFa cookies to the request it succeded. This makes me curious as to what exactly you mean by "does not require extra authentication to succeed". As best I can tell from your request there is no initial authentication.

I also verified that without the cookies I get a 403 at the site collection level as well.  You don't mention where you're generating these requests from but I'd step through and determine why your cookies are not being added to the request.